# Prove $ f $ is identically zero if $f(0)=0$ and $|f′(x)|\le|f(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I'm working on Omar Hijab's Introduction to Calculus and Classical Analysis
and meet this question:

Let $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $f(0) = 0$ and $|f'(x)|≤|f(x)|$ for
all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f = 0$.

I know this question has been answered before, but I want to solve it following the book's solution, the solution is:

Let $g(x) = f(x)^2$. Then $g'(x) ≤ 2g(x)$, so $e^{−2x}g(x)$ has nonpositive
derivative and $e^{−2x}g(x) ≤ g(0) = 0$. Thus $f$ is identically zero.

I'm able to get $e^{−2x}g(x)$ has nonpositive derivative, that gives:$$\frac{e^{-2x}g(x)-g(0)}{x} \le 0$$
However I can only see it follows the solution when $ x \ge 0$, if $x \le 0$ then it becomes: $$e^{−2x}g(x) \ge g(0)$$ What did I miss? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you clarify what $x$ is in $\frac{e^{-2x}g(x)-g(0)}{x} \le 0$?

Comment: Hi Ragon, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \not= 0$, as the function came directly from $(e^{-2x}g(x))'$ at $x=0$. Hope this is the answer you want

Comment: For $x < 0$, replace $f(x)$ by $f(-x)$ and use the $x > 0$ situation.

Comment: Maybe you can also give us the number of the exercise in the book and the page

Comment: Edition 4, question 3.2.7, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the actual derivative of $e^{-2x} g(x)$ instead of appealing to the mean value theorem.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-2x} g(x)) = e^{-2x}(g'(x) - 2g(x)) \le 0$$
since you already showed $g'(x) \le 2g(x)$.

---

Response to comment:

You can also show that $-g'(x) \le 2g(x)$. This implies that the derivative of $e^{2x} g(x)$, which is $e^{2x}(g'(x) + 2g(x))$, is nonnegative. Then $e^{2x} g(x) \le g(0)$ for $x \le 0$.

Comment: This gets me 'nonpositive derivative', I don't know how to approach $e^{−2x}g(x)≤g(0)$

Comment: @OLalalala Sorry I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer to address the missing case.

Comment: I think this one works, thank you! @angryavian